# Pull MySQL Database Value Continously

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing a number in a MySql Database Table, specifically a row called "open" whose field is an integer value that nearly continuously changes. I want to be able to continuously pull this value and display it on the frontend HTML page and put it in a table, called something like "live values". I want the numbers on the frontend to change without need for page refresh and I am trying to figure out how/if I can do this.

Is it possible to pull the value of the data to the frontend, using PHP, asynchronously?

Comment: Use AJAX, request a PHP page that does the query.

Comment: With most programming things, you have to give up the idea of "continuous." With this, you'd need to poll every few seconds; otherwise, you start to overload your server and increase your badwidth usage to incredible amounts.

Comment: @drderp updating the number every 5 seconds or so would be fine, but I do not want to refresh. As for bandwidth, this is an internal app use by 10 people.

Comment: @chriscct7 It was just a warning, because I remember someone took down userscripts.org by accidentally putting an AJAX request every 100 milliseconds in his script, causing a supposed DDoS attack on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to program a little bit of JavaScript in the HTML itself, which will periodically poll a PHP page. This PHP page should access the MySQL DB, retrieve the number, and send it back.

Here's Google AJAX tutorial which might help you: http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html

Simpler PHP + AJAX examples:

http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/simple_ajax

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Any chance you know of a tutorial that is a little closer to what I want? I just want to pull one number....the Google guide is very vague.

Comment: See the answer; I've added two more.